# Access session variable in qweb template odoo 8

Tags: templates, session, odoo-8, qweb

I have added a new key value pair into session in controller file like below:

```
request.session['new_key']= new_value
```

And i need to access this new key in my qweb template!
I tried:

```
  <t t-esc="website.new_key"/> and 
  <t t-esc="env.new_key"/>
```

Nothing works, but it works

```
  <t t-esc="env.uid"/> 
  <t t-esc="website.user_id"/>
```

And another doubt is, where can i add new key value a pair into session during successfully login?
Please suggest any solution... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler - you can do this:

```
<t t-esc="request.session.new_key" />
```

(maybe also request.session['new_key'] but I have not tried that).